# Change tab bar colour in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

How do I change the colour of the tab bar in iOS 7? So, far I have changed the colour of the navigation bar using the following:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.376 green:0.729 blue:0.318 alpha:1.000];
```

However I would like to change the colour of the tab bar that was created with my Xcode project within the Storyboard file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you open up your Tab Bar Controller scene in the storyboard, you should see a Tab Bar Controller with a Tab Bar object as a child object. Select the Tab Bar object and open up the Attributes Inspector. You can change the tint color by modifying the Bar Tint property right under the Style drop down.

To modify it programatically, try this:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.376 green:0.729 blue:0.318 alpha:1.000];
```

Comment: That's great thanks, how would you do this programmatically if possible?

Comment: Updated the answer. It assumes you have a property called tabBarController.

Comment: Should only be one UIColor though within the square brackets ;)